# recursive d3 animation issue

Tags: javascript, animation, recursion, d3.js

I am trying to run an animation using d3 by chaining animations together with recursion.  I have a function animate that calls itself like this until all the animations are chained together

```
(function animate(transition) {
    // code here

    animate(transition.transition())
})(selection.transition());
```

The visualization itself works, but I'm trying to keep track of how many times the function has been called so I can display it on screen in sync with the animation.  However, the recursion chains the transitions together before the first one even finishes, so my counter is always just the number of the last transition.

Here's [a jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/84qUq/1/) that shows what I'm trying to do.  What is strange is that the radius of the circles are set correctly, i.e. when setting attributes it gets the proper count, while in the same call of animate it's incorrect.  I've looked at old stack overflow questions, and I've looked through the d3 docs, and I can't find a good way to keep track of the count throughout the recursion.  Does anyone know of such a way?

Answer (score 0):

Your recursive function runs immediately - replace `count++;` with `console.log(count++);` - and you'll see the console will be filled with 1, 2, 3, ..., 59 right away. The transitions keep playing slowly because d3 automatically [chains transitions](https://github.com/mbostock/d3/wiki/Transitions#wiki-transition), so:

```
svg.selectAll('circle')
  .transition().style("fill","pink")
  .transition().duration(10000).style("fill", "green")
  .transition().duration(400).style("fill", "red")
```

will turn the all the circles in `svg` pink, then green slowly, then red quickly. The recursive function you have basically chains together a big long list of 60 transitions and d3 slowly plays it out.

I'm not sure about the best place in your code to keep the count synced with the animation - maybe someone else can chime in? I would probably use [d3.timer](https://github.com/mbostock/d3/wiki/Transitions#timers) instead of a wonky recursive function.

Comment: Right. It chains them together then plays them slowly, which would be just what I want if I had some way to save the count variable to each transition.  I've come up with a sort of hacky way to do it, which is to chain transitions to the counter in parallel like this
    `(function animate(circle_trans, counter_trans) {
        // ...

        counter_trans.call(function() {
            counter_trans.__data__ = count;
        });

        // ...
        animate(circle_trans.transition(), counter_trans.transition());
})();`
But I feel like there should be an easier way